# Python: Request POST method is not uploading a fie to the web server

Tags: python, python-requests

I am stuck with this problem that I have had for a while.

I have code here that is intended to upload a file to a web server.

```py
class uploadFile_Functions():

    def __init__(self, DESTINATION_URL, TARGET_FILE):
        self.DESTINATION_URL = DESTINATION_URL
        self.TARGET_FILE = TARGET_FILE

    def uploadFile_WebServ(self):
        dest_site = self.DESTINATION_URL
        t_file = self.TARGET_FILE

    with open(t_file,'rb') as f:
        print('Uploading the file to the server')
        upload_req = requests.post(dest_site, files={t_file:f})
        print('Upload successful')
```

The `dest_site` will contain the link to the webpage folder that I have, and the `t_file` will contain the file to be uploaded.

What happens is that when I run this code, there were no errors thrown during runtime, and the shell printed the 'Upload successful' statement. But I checked the webpage folder in chrome, and the file is not even there.

I do not know if this needs some sort of authentication since this is a web server. I was able to get a file from the same webpage folder using the GET method, but no success so far with the POST method.

I appreciate any answer that I get from you guys. Thank you!

Comment: Could be a caching issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @SamMorgan. What does it mean, like the code is forgetting that it is uploading a file somehow? I would really appreciate if you would elaborate what this means.

Comment: Well, how are you checking that the file made it to the server? Are you performing a GET request from your code, or are you browsing to the page in a web browser? If it's the latter, you could be viewing a cached version of the page and just need to clear your local cache before the new information will show.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I was viewing the page thru chrome for verification. Let me clear the cache and check if there would be any changes. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @SamMorgan I've cleared everything, and restarted my workstation, but it looks like the file is still not present there...